# Exponential function (t)

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I got the function $8.513 \times 1.00531^{\Large t} = 10$. The task is to solve $t$. The correct answer is $t = 31$. How do I get there ?.

Comment: Note to the confused Americans: much of the rest of the world uses decimal-commas instead of decimal-points as the radix symbol. Carry on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&8.513\times 1.00531^{t}=10\ \imp\ 1.00531^{t}={10 \over 8.513}\ \imp\
\ln\pars{1.00531^{t}} = \ln\pars{10 \over 8.513}
\\[3mm]&\imp t\ln\pars{1.00531} = \ln\pars{10 \over 8.513}\ \imp\
\color{#66f}{\large t = {\ln\pars{10/8.513} \over \ln\pars{1.00531}}}
\approx {\tt 30.3988}
\end{align}

Comment: In the future, please don't rush to post nothing but "$8.513 \times $" (to be first to post, I assume), delete your answer, then write a complete answer to reopen later.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $\log(ab^c)=\log a + c\log b$

Answer (score 1):

- Isolate $ 1.00531^{\large t}$ on the left side of the equation.
- Take the $\ln$ of each side of that equation.
- And use the fact that $\ln a^b = b \ln a$.
- Solve for $t$ as you would any first degree polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$8.513 \cdot 1.00531^t=10 \iff 1.00531^t=\frac{10}{8.513} \iff \ln[1.00531^t]=\ln\left[\frac{10}{8.513}\right] $$
$$\iff t\ln[1.00531]=\ln\left[\frac{10}{8.513}\right] \iff t= \quad?$$